# lambda function on a numpy array. What's wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

What's wrong with this code :

import numpy as np

```
A = np.array([[-0.5, 0.2, 0.0],
          [4.2, 3.14, -2.7]])

asign = lambda t: 0 if t<0 else 1
asign(A)
print(A)
```

expected out:

```
     [[0.  1.  0.]
      [ 1.  1. 0.]]
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What would you expect the answer to `np.array([[-0.5, 0.2, 0.0], [4.2, 3.14, -2.7]]) < 0` to be? Python doesn't know how to handle that kind of comparison.

Comment: Try to compare `A < 0`. This makes no sense. I think you want smth like `B = [assign(a) for a in x for x in A]` or anything else.

Comment: `A<0` produces a boolean array the same size as `A`.  Python `if` only works with a scalar boolean True/False.  It's a simple either/or action.  It can't work with multiple boolean values.

Comment: Thank you. i implemented using clip and np.sign()

Comment: Note, the lambda function is not really relevant. In any case, if you are going to *assign your anonymous function to a name*, you should just use a regular function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the lambda on its own will not go through the whole array. For that you will need a higher order function. In this case: map.

```
A = np.array([[-0.5, 0.2, 0.0],
              [4.2, 3.14, -2.7]])

asign = lambda t: 0 if t<0 else 1
A = list(map(asign, A))
```

Map will iterate through every element and pass it through the function.
I wrapped map in a list because it returns an object of type map but you can convert it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lambda, but the `numpy` datatypes allow you to do many "matlab-type" operations (for those who are used to that):

- python:

  ```
  a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  ((a > 1) & (a < 3)).astype(int)
  # array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
  ```
- octave/matlab

  ```
  a = [1,2,3,4,5];
  a>1 & a<3
  % ans =
  %
  %  0  1  0  0  0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
A = A.clip(min=0, max=1)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just use `(A > 0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, sorry, but more data. I also can't find the explanation for the fact that some functions/lambdas act over the array, while the others treat it as a whole.

See this testing:

```py
string_arr = [ "a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd" ]
ndstr_arr = np.array(string_arr)
l1 = lambda x: x == "ccc"
l2 = lambda x: len(x) > 2

print("\nDirect lambda over array:")
print (l1(string_arr)) # fails
print (l2(string_arr)) # fails
print (l1(ndstr_arr))  # WORKS
print (l2(ndstr_arr))  # fails

print("\nList(map(lambda over array)): ")
print (list(map(l1,string_arr))) # WORKS
print (list(map(l2,string_arr))) # WORKS
print (list(map(l1,ndstr_arr)))  # WORKS
print (list(map(l2,ndstr_arr)))  # WORKS
```

for this result:

```
Direct lambda over array:
False
True
[False False  True False]
True

List(map(lambda over array)): 
[False, False, True, False]
[False, False, True, True]
[False, False, True, False]
[False, False, True, True]
```

Both lambda's are boolean functions, but for some reason the first one `x==...` gets mapped over the array (and note: only over the ndarray - the regular list, string_arr is never mapped) whereas `len(x) > 2` acts on the array as single object.
What's the difference between these lambdas?

(Also note that list(map) is not a real substitute since it doesn't return an ndarray, so we have to use it to build a new ndarray or use vectorize or some other method... that's not really the point here though)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own follow-on question which sort of answers the original.
To recap / generalize:

The OP is asking **"Why is the lambda applied to the numpy array as a whole object when I expected it to be applied element-wise?"**

My followup asks **"Why are *some* lambda applied as a whole while others are applied element_wise?"**

The TL;DR answer is that the lambda *always* treats the numpy array as a whole object - a regular argument to a regular function - but the *operator* used *inside* the body of the lambda (or function, or wherever) *may* be overridden by numpy ndarray to work *element-wise*, and the `==` operator is such and operator.

In my example it's the `==` operator. I tracked down the override for this and unfortunately the [official numpy documentation of the override](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__eq__.html) is *not much help*:

> numpy.ndarray.**eq** method
>
> ndarray.**eq**(value, /) Return self==value.

(fwiw, I know this is the documenation for == because the equivalency of operators to special method names is defined in [this python reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__))

The correct answer required more digging - I found it in the [numpy documentation of the `numpy.equal` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html):

> numpy.equal numpy.equal(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, where=True,
> casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature,
> extobj]) = <ufunc 'equal'>
>
> Return (x1 == x2) **element-wise.**

The `==` operator is applied *element-wise*!

Hence in my first lambda
`lambda x: x == "ccc"`, `x` does indeed hold the entire ndarray, but the `==` is applied to each element returning *a new ndarray*

Again the [`numpy.equal` doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) makes this clear:

> Returns: out: ndarray or scalar
>
> Output array, element-wise comparison
> of x1 and x2. Typically of type bool, unless dtype=object is passed.
> This is a scalar if both x1 and x2 are scalars.

`x1` and `x2` are the args, so that we're comparing `x1 == x2`. In our case, `x1` is `x` so the full ndarray - not scalar - so the result is an ndarray.

You may be wondering why how it treats `"ccc"` (which is assigned to the `x2` parameter), the doc says:

> Parameters
>
> x1, x2 array_like
>
> Input arrays. If x1.shape != x2.shape,
> they must be broadcastable to a common shape (which becomes the shape
> of the output).

So `x2` (our `"ccc"`) is supposed to be array_like, but numpy will, if it can, *broadcast* it to the same shape as `x1`. And it will, because it can, as is documented in [Numpy Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

> The simplest broadcasting example occurs when an array and a scalar
> value are combined in an operation...
>
> The result is equivalent to the previous example where b was an array.
> We can think of the scalar b being stretched during the arithmetic
> operation into an array with the same shape as a.

QED.